# Design Pattern For Using Google Maps API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3

I have address fields in my rails 3.2.2 app consisting of @address.address1, @address.city, @address.state, and @address.zip.  Looking at the Google Map API:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[SOME ADDRESS]&zoom=14&size=512x512&sensor=false" />
```

I'm trying to figure out the best strategy of assembling my address fields and inserting into the URL above which ultimately goes in my erb file.

For example, is the best way just to use

```
 <%= image_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[SOME ADDRESS]&zoom=14&size=512x512&sensor=false" %>
```

and if so, how can I append the fields to the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the address in to one string:

```
address = [@address.address1, @address.city, @address.state, @address.zip].join(", ")
```

Encode the string to include in a URL:

```
require 'uri'
address = URI.escape(address)
```

Create a image tag:

```
<%= image_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{address}&zoom=14&size=512x512&sensor=false" %>
```